# Bash script ignores all terminal input following an underscore

Tags: bash, alias, stdout, stdin, slurm

**Goal**

My server manages jobs using SLURM. Each job in the queue has a job ID, which can be either a single integer or two integers separated by an underscore, e.g., `123_4`. You can use `scontrol show job [job ID]` to print some general info about the job, including the name of the file that stores the standard output (specifically, there is a line that says `StdOut=/path/to/stdout/file`). All I want to do is write an alias that takes the ID from the terminal input and opens this file in vim.

**My attempt**

`alias checkout='vi $(scontrol show job $1 | grep StdOut | cut -d'=' -f 2)`

**The problem**

When I try `checkout 123_4`, the script ignores the `_4` part. This is a problem because in practice, this part is the array ID, and there will be many jobs in a single array. Hence, `scontrol` will print a bunch of `StdOut=...` lines, and vim will open a bunch of files (for jobs 123_1, 123_2, etc.). The issue must be in how `$1` reads in the terminal input, but I couldn't figure out how to fix that. For example, I tried replacing it with `$@` and `$*`, and doing something like `"${1}"` to no avail.

I figure this should be an easy fix for anyone more experienced with bash!

Comment: Aliases don't take positional parameters like `$1` - I suspect what's really happening is that `$1` is expanding to an empty string, and you're running `scontrol show job` without a job ID, which is therefore listing all jobs by default.

Comment: Use a shell function instead of an alias to handle arguments. Your code seems to have problems with quoting. There is an odd number of single quotes.